# Allocating more VRAM to Javafx Program

Tags: java, optimization, javafx, parameters, vram

I am working on a JavaFX program and want to speed up my application. After reading about large images and issues related to them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27840362/javafx-large-image-crash), I decided to follow the advice there and allocate more VRAM. I am not quite sure how to do this, however, although I have an idea of how to do it I would like specific instructions to do so. The parameter I need to use is Dprism.maxvram=XX. I am using the eclipse IDE and would like to know where in it do I insert the parameter and will the parameter be carried when exporting to a jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse, to change build arguments, go to Run -> Run configurations... and then select Arguments.

Add `-Dprism.maxvram=whatever` to your VM arguments (not Program arguments, these are the `args[]` passed to your `main` method)

This will not carry over to your .JAR file, because parameters must be passed through the command line and are not stored in the file itself.

You could create a batch file to run the JAR for you with your specified arguments, though.

Example batch file:

```
java -Dprism.maxvram=90M -jar MyJar.jar
```

Then you'd just have to double click your bat file to run your JAR with 90MB of VRAM.

Answer (score 2):

The JavaFX deployment guide specifies [mechanisms to pass parameters to the JVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packaging.html#BABJHDFJ) on startup. These will work if you launch the application either as a "self-contained application bundle", or if you launch via web start. In short, you can use

```xml
<fx:platform javafx="8.0+">
    <fx:property name="prism.maxvram" value="90M"/>
</fx:platform>
```

in your JavaFX Ant build file, or use the option

```
-BjvmProperties=prism.maxvram=90M
```

to the [`javapackager` tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html).